# @-webkit-keyframes clashing with others

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I have a keyframe animation effect on 2 banners on my homepage. I have defined each banner to have a different class so I could choose a different speed for each animation. The HTML looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="subpage-image-sca">
        <span class="subpage-image ken-burns-container">
            <img src="http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Header-Image-homepage-compressor.jpg" class="ken-burns-image">
        </span>
</div>


<div class="subpage-image-sca">
        <span class="subpage-image ken-burns-container-20">
            <img src="http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Header-Image-homepage-compressor.jpg" class="ken-burns-image-20">
        </span>
</div>
```

The CSS Code looks like this:

**CSS**

```
/* ------------ Ken Burns 10 Secs ------------- */

.ken-burns-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ken-burns-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: border-box;
  animation: 10s ease-in 0s 1 scaleout;
  -webkit-animation: 10s ease-in 0s 1 scaleout;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
   100% {transform: scale(20); 
    }
  }



/* ------------ Ken Burns 20 Secs ------------- */

.ken-burns-container-20 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ken-burns-image-20 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: border-box;
  animation: 20s ease-in 0s 1 scaleout;
  -webkit-animation: 20s ease-in 0s 1 scaleout;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
   100% {transform: scale(1.17); 
    }
  }
```

Heres a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shan_2000_uk/yhf4dzrx/10/

Both of these bits of CSS work fine on their own. It seems that there is a conflict with the last block of code that defines the scale:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
   100% {transform: scale(20); 
    }
  }
```

If I remove this block from either of the sections, the other works fine.

I have tried adding the class to this block like so:

```
.ken-burns-container-20 @-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
   100% {transform: scale(1.17); 
    }
  }
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know, A: Why the code is conflicting and B: A way to use both bits of code without them conflicting?

Thanks a lot for taking the time to look!

Comment: Let's start with `keyframes` haven't needed vendor prefixing for some time.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D - So would the prefixing be causing the issue do you think?

Comment: No...firstly, I'm not clear on what it is you are trying to achieve by you can't have tow animations with the same name...as it is, neither of them does anything.

Comment: Oh, ok I didn't realise, I thought I could use the same animation name as long as it was being applied to two different classes... So I'm hoping then that if I use scaleout and scaleout2 for example, it will work... I will have a check...

Comment: You can use the same animation but you can't change the basic properties (the actual keyframes)...timing/delay/direction/easing etc can be changed but not the actual thing you are animating.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand, thank you! I have changed the name of the animations too: scaleout-one and scaleout-two and it seems to enable me to control each of them with separate scale values! If you would like to type it up as an answer, I can mark it as correct? :) Thanks again!

Comment: I will also try and tidy it up and remove the Prefixing if its no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just overriding the first `@keyframe` rule with the last one, you'll probably need to name them with different names, let's *scaleout1* for the first `@keyframe` and *scaleout2* for the last `@keyframe`.

Here's a demo:

```css
.ken-burns-container, .ken-burns-container-20 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ken-burns-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: border-box;
  animation: scaleout1 10s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.ken-burns-image-20 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-clip: border-box;
  animation: scaleout2 20s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* keyframes */
@keyframes scaleout1 {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(20); }
}
@keyframes scaleout2 {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  100% { transform: scale(1.17); }
}
```

```html
<div class="subpage-image-sca">
    <span class="subpage-image ken-burns-container">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="ken-burns-image">
    </span>
</div>
<div class="subpage-image-sca">
    <span class="subpage-image ken-burns-container-20">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500" class="ken-burns-image-20">
    </span>
</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.